# How to handle the exceptions thrown due to NullValue property from DataColumn?

Tags: c#, null, dataset, datacolumn

I have a DataSet that I made it with a wizard. This DataSet has a DataTable with ID column whose NullValue property is set to (Throw exception). How can I handle this kind of exception in code? For example show my message or do something else.

Comment: Which programming language? In your code null value is acceptable or not?

Comment: Knowing the programming language involved would make helping you a lot easier. Is it java? Python? etc..?

Comment: The AllowDBNull property for this ID column is set to false, so null value isn't acceptable. And the language is C# in win forms apps. Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest that you ensure that the column never gets a null value.